# Problem running the Android Studio emulator on AMD CPU

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, emulation, amd-processor

Recently I decided to learn android dev with Kotlin, I installed JDK, the latest Android Studio release and other stuff but my CPU is AMD so I cannot install intel's HAXM which is required to launch the emulator . I want to know if an equivalent for pc with AMD exist

Comment: check this out https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html

Comment: 26/12/2019
13:36 Emulator: PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

13:36 Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 3):

For your problem there are several ways to fix the issue.

1. Android Studio with Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors Tools(Recommended)

Here's the full [document](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/12/emulator-29211-and-amd-hypervisor-12-to.html)

Go to Android SDK -> SDK Tools -> Check `Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors` also make sure if they're installed they're updated, since this solution got a problem with using NOX player at same time, and causing `Blue Screen of Death`

Then go to App & Features -> Turn windows features on or off -> make sure Hyper-V and Windows Hypervisor Platform are disabled. All Windows features enabling Hyper-V either explicitly or silently must be turned off.

2. Other solution is to use Nox or Bluestack emulator. i prefer nox since idk why but bluestack using so many resource, and also nox multi-instance is also working very well for using several emulators and it's got 3 version of android (4, 5, 7).

Common issues while using nox when trying to develop flutter app or etc is sometime emulator won't appear in your emulator list in android studio which the solution is that you should copy your adb nox file to your android sdk folder. or address the `PATH VARIABLES` to use nox adb.

Good Luck.